# Fat Semicolon for Function Composition in Diagrammatic Order

Tags: symbols, unicode-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Is there a LaTeX macro that produces the [fat semicolon symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a3e/index.htm)? As noted in Wikipedia,

> A further variation encountered in computer science is the Z notation: $\circ$ is used to denote the traditional (right) composition, but (a fat semicolon with Unicode code point U+2A3E[2]) denotes left composition. This use of semicolon coincides with the notation for function composition used (mostly by computer scientists) in Category theory.

Comment: You usually can find the answer to questions like this by looking in the comprehensive symbols list (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/). In Table 46 in said document you may find that the `stmaryrd` package has a `\fatsemi` command that gives yo uthe fat semicolonn.